# Compare values in vector and if next value is greater or equal to any of previous values then make it NA

Tags: r

In the vector below, I want to compare values in the vector and if the next value is greater or equal to all the previous values in `vec`, then I want to make it NA

```
vec = c(14.2, 3.7, 2.875, 2.175, 1.575, 1.1, 0.7, 0.475, 0.3, 0.65, 0.125, 0.925, 0.025, 0.025, 0.015, 0.020)
```

Following is the expected output

```
vec = c(14.2, 3.7, 2.875, 2.175, 1.575, 1.1, 0.7, 0.475, 0.3, NA, 0.125, NA, 0.025, NA, 0.015, NA)
```

Following is the performance of the solutions below -

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
TarJae = vec[c(which(vec >= shift(vec, n = 1L, type = "lag")))] <- NA,
onyambu = replace(vec, vec > cummin(vec) | duplicated(vec), NA),
times = 1000)

    expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
  TarJae  41.846  44.1550  49.79315  46.2705  47.7505 2742.726  1000  b 
 onyambu  18.066  19.4435  21.21144  20.3280  21.3395   69.071  1000 a
```

Comment: in the case of `10, 12, 11` , which one should be NA? or there should be no NA?

Comment: In this case, the output would be ```10, NA, NA```

Comment: Why do you have both 12 and 11 as NA?

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention, all the values on the right side should be less than all values on left side.

Comment: and which ones do you turn to NA? the right values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is:

```
replace(vec, vec > cummin(vec) | duplicated(vec), NA)
[1] 14.200  3.700  2.875  2.175  1.575  1.100  0.700  0.475  0.300     NA  0.125     NA  0.025  NA
```

or even:

```
`is.na<-`(vec, vec > cummin(vec)|duplicated(vec))
[1] 14.200  3.700  2.875  2.175  1.575  1.100  0.700  0.475  0.300     NA  0.125     NA  0.025  NA
```

Comment: @Saurabh Note that Tarjae solution will fail in cases such as c(10,12,11,9)

Comment: Somehow this solution is not working on following vector. ```vec = c(606.2, 446.65, 407.9, 367.2, 347.25, 156, 122, 105.25, 90, 83.25, 76, 63.9, 51.25, 49.4, 46.25, 41, 31.95, 26.9, 26, 24.85, 23.25, 21.3, 20.35, 18.65, 17.4, 16.4, 14.6, 13.65, 12.65, 11.5, 10.7, 10.5, 9.55, 8.3, 8, 7.55, 6.75, 5.85, 5.85, 4.6, 4.525, 4.275, 3.9, 3.225, 3.425, 2.7, 1.75, 1.75, 2.85, 2.025, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.425, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.275, 1.725, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)```

Comment: @Saurabh You do have `NA`s the `cummin` of `c(NA, 6)` will just be NA and thus any number greater than NA is FALSE. consider converting NA's to a number, either fill forward or fill with the first value before doing `cummin`

Answer (score 4):

As noted by @onyambu this solution will not work in case of `**10, 12, 11**`

**`library(dplyr) vec[c(which(vec >= lag(vec)))] <- NA`**

Update to the updated question: basically it is the same answer:

```
library(dplyr)

vec = c(14.2, 3.7, 2.875, 2.175, 1.575, 1.1, 0.7, 0.475, 0.3, 0.65, 0.125, 0.925, 0.025, 0.025, 0.015, 0.020)

vec[c(which(vec >= lag(vec)))] <- NA
vec

[1] 14.200  3.700  2.875  2.175  1.575  1.100  0.700  0.475  0.300     NA  0.125     NA  0.025     NA  0.015     NA
```

We could use `lag` then compare both vectors , get the index with `which` and assign NA to this indices:

```
library(dplyr)

vec[c(which(vec > lag(vec)))] <- NA

[1] 14.200  3.700  2.875  2.175  1.575  1.100  0.700  0.475  0.300     NA  0.125     NA
```

Comment: then your expected output changes also?

Comment: Please see my update. The solution is the correct answer as you can see it gives again the expected solution.

Comment: Ahhh I got it it is not > it is >=. please see my update.

Comment: ah it is `library(dplyr)` ! load it! then it works.

Comment: This will not work in the case of `vec <- c(10,12,11,10, 9)`

Comment: I think it will work. It depends I guess on what is desired. Compared to the expected output. the op implicates that after NA the next number is the first to consider. Therefore: 12 is bigger then 10 e.g. NA. 11 is the next -> is smaller, 10 is next and is smaller then 11, next is 9 and is smaller then the before. so the output is `[1] 10 NA 11 10  9` the correct one. I think main assumption is that NA breaks all previous values and starts with new. ?

Comment: Note that it should give 10, NA,NA,NA,9. I did ask OP before I deleted my comments. I felt like diff was not enough

Comment: check the comments below the question. I do have 10,12,11 and OP responds by 10,NA,NA

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ifelse(c(vec[2]-vec[1] , diff(vec)) < 0 , vec , NA)
```